# Why there is a ? mark in if-let statement to see an optional has a value

Tags: swift

I am reading the following book, on Page #32 there is a code snippet. December 2014: First Edition.

> Swift Development with CocoaJonathon Manning, Paris Buttfield-Addison,
> and Tim Nugent

I know we can use `?` to make a vairbale optional and `!` to unwrap a optional vairbale in Swift

```
var str: String? = "string"
if let theStr = str? {
    println("\(theStr)")
} else {
    println("nil")
}
```

Why do we need `?` in this line `if let theStr = str?` It seems working just fine with out it and making no difference.

---

[image]

Comment: Why do you think you need to ? in the if let?

Comment: I am reading "Swift Development with Cocoa
Jonathon Manning, Paris Buttfield-Addison, and Tim Nugent" this book, its a provided example

Comment: if let str = str { println("\(str)") }

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus I know this works. My question is why we do need `?` in the optional binding. `if let newStr = str? {...}`

Comment: You don't need to create a second var for every optional you have in your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need it, and shouldn't have it. The optional binding evaluates the optional. If it's nil, it stops. If it's not nil, it assigns the value to your required variable and then executes the code inside the braces of the if statement.

### EDIT:

The language has changed slightly since it was first given out in beta form. My guess is that the ? used to be required.

Some of the sample projects I've used from Github fail to compile and I've had to edit them to get them to work. this might be an example where the syntax has changed slightly.

Comment: Do you know where I can find more reference for `if-let` statement? and additonal `?` does not make the code fail to compile atleast in **Playground**.

Comment: @X.Li Use the official documentation. It's the only one kept up-to-date.

Comment: Apple's iBook, "The Swift Programming Language" has a section on optional bindings (which is what the "if let" construct is called.)

Answer (score 1):

The current version of Swift does not require it, as it is redundant since your variable is already an optional.

Whatever you put in the if let statement does have to be an optional though or you will receive an error

> Bound Value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type

Furthermore, if you are casting to a type, you do need to use `as?` to cast to an optional type.

```
var str2: Any = ["some", "example"]

if let theStr = str2 as? [String] {
    println("\(theStr)")
} else {
    println("nil")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for extending the answer to type casting